# Will 1950s era cellulose fiber acoustical ceiling tiles (verified non asbestos) break down in compost pile?

Tags: disposal, ceiling-tiles

We've got a lot of old 1950s era cellulose fiber acoustic ceiling tiles to dispose of. We've had samples tested and verified not to contain asbestos. My thought is just to put them in the compost bin - is there any reason to think they are not compostable? We are severely limited in the volume of trash we can put out, but essentially unlimited for compostables and for recyclables.

Comment: Celluious fiber should break down, but the stuff that holds it together might not.  Imagine the compost is pickup and not in the back yard.  Your local recyclers should be able to give a yes/no answer if they allow it for compost or recycling.

Comment: @crip659 It turns out to be a bit tricky to get a proper answer, as the default answer here in the SF Bay Area (which gets them more money) is to talk of it as construction debris/materials without really investigating. The fibers are now only loosely bound, as a little rubbing between the fingers fully separates them. Perhaps I can try some home "tests" spraying some with water and letting them sit outside.